# PHP: Interactive Contact form not working

Tags: php, forms, email

***Why is this form not working?***

I'm creating a form that sends messages to users.

The user email comes from the database.
The query that searches the database is influenced by some data sent previously to the browser.

***The problem at the moment is:***
When one clicks to submit, nothing really happens.

Got a file called mini-contact.php with the following:

Script to proccess the form:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$company=$_GET['company'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE companies.companyID= '$company'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $companyemail = $row['Email_Address'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "tiagomartinsperes@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
        $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
        $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
        $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

        $header = "From:" . $from; 
        $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

        $header2 = "From:" . $to;
        $header2.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $header2.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
        $header2.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

        $status1 = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        $status2 = mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$header2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender

        if($status1 and $status2){
            $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
            echo 'Mail Sent. Thank you' . $first_name . ', we will contact you shortly.';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, Please try again!</p>';
        }
// You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
}
}
?>
```

The actual form:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="">
     <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="controls">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 no-left-pad">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>First Name *</label>
                      <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your first name" required="required" data-error="First name is required.">
                       <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 no-left-pad">
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name *</label>
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your last name" required="required" data-error="Last name is required.">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 no-left-pad">
                    <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Email *</label>
                              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 no-left-pad">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Phone</label>
                              <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 no-left-pad">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Subject</label>
                              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Example: Service Request ">
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 no-left-pad">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Message *</label>
                              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message" rows="4" required="required" data-error=" Please enter your message."></textarea>
                              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 no-left-pad">
                              <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 no-left-pad">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default caps" name="submit" value="Submit">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

**Thank you for your time**

Comment: try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code.  You could be getting errors because your closing `}` on your `if` blocks are commented out.

Comment: thank you, that helped partially.
Was problem in the script, had the wrong page name, but now the form doesn't post

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Do you see anything in Developer tools?

Comment: Also, try putting `var_dump($_POST)` towards the top of your php and see if there is anything there.

Comment: As you can see, did some changes in the php.

Atm, the data gets posted into an array.
Still, the email doesn't get sent.
Also, the php.ini is well configured.

No errors are shown in the console

What can be the problem here?

Comment: do you know _which_ of the two mails is not sending? At the moment the program can't distinguish. Presumably either $status1 or $status2 (or both) is false? Or are they returning true, but the emails are not delivered? Even a "success" result from the `mail` function does not guarantee delivery of an email. Something else in the subsystem could be wrong. Or the mail could be sent, but never received (e.g. rejected as spam or otherwise lost). PS. You are telling the world your email address, maybe better to edit it for the purpose of the question.

Comment: think found the problem. Forgot to set the SMTP credentials, of course wouldn't work without it. Let me test it and will let you know asap

Comment: Don't put [solved] in the title, post an answer with the solution. Or, if it was a non-reproducible case (with the information given it sure looks like that), delete the question.

Comment: Forgot the SMPT credentials. Now it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to have SMPT properly configure so that it works.